# ionic loop lendo sensor e enviando para api

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic3, async, promises

Olá, preciso realizar leituras consecutivas de alguns sensores no ionic 3.x porém não posso deixar que isso trave completamente a aplicação. tentei fazer assim:

```js
  async disparaLeituras(path_id) {
    while (true) {
      console.log('laço');
      try {
        var gyscope_data = await this.deviceMotion.getCurrentAcceleration();
        console.log(gyscope_data)
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e); // 30
      }

    }
  }
```

porém isso fez com que aplicação travasse completamente, além do sensor de aceleração eu verifico o giroscopio e o gps tambem, todos eles retornam promisses, alguém sabe a forma correta de proceder?

Comment: O jeito mais fácil é usar como uma promise padrão em vez de usar `await`, mas talvez isso não ajude no seu caso de uso. O que você vai fazer com esses dados depois?

Comment: eu envio pra uma api dps, se eu tirar o wait vou diparar varias promisses e vai acabar travando tbm

Comment: talze usar recurção seja uma soluçao, dps q a promisse realiza uma leitura ela dispara a proxima

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De fato, fazer diversas requisições por segundos pode prejudicar o desempenho do app e do backend.

Você pode usar o `watchAcceleration` e os operadores do `rxjs` para limitar e / ou agrupar os dados do acelerômetro.

Algunas opções de solução são

- Juntar leituras por *n* segundos e enviar em batch (com [bufferTime](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/buffertime.html) e [mergeMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html)):

```
import { bufferTime, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

(...)

this.deviceMotion.watchAcceleration().pipe(
    bufferTime(2000),
    mergeMap(groupedData => this.apiService.sendBatchData(groupedData)),
).subscribe(response => {
    // Response da api
});
```

- Coletar a última leitura a cada *n* segundos, descartando leituras intermediárias (com [debounceTime](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/debouncetime.html)):

```
import { debounceTime, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

(...)

this.deviceMotion.watchAcceleration().pipe(
    debounceTime(2000),
    mergeMap(singleData => this.apiService.sendData(singleData)),
).subscribe(response => {
    // Response da api
});
```

Entre outras. A solução ideal vai depender do seu caso de uso.

Comment: o debouncetime seria o equivalente a rodar uma funçao de litura e envio a cada n segundos?

Comment: Não diria que é equivalente. Pode até ser parecido. Mas usando o `watchAcceleration` você muda o fluxo do programa e, ao invés de **pedir** e esperar a resposta do acelerômetro a cada _n_ millisegundos, **você será notificado sempre que houver uma atualização**. Então, você pode fazer o que quiser com os dados que chegaram: descartar, agrupar, etc,.de forma muito mais declarativa.